# How do you view Entity Framework calls in SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

I have a project that utilizes Entity Framework.  I want to run SQL Server Profiler to see how many calls are being made to the database.  I've enabled almost every different event possible to trace, but still I don't see the events being triggered.

I've searched online and it appears that a few tools are available to purchase.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what ORM you are using - if it's hitting the database the statements will show up in Profiler.  Have you confirmed that the application is hitting the same SQL instance that you are monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue.  I assumed Entity Framework was loading all of the entities when the web app started.  I had to call a entity first for the queries to show up.

Comment: This is usually known as "Lazy loading", for reference :)